# Issue with making a POST call to a REST service from as3

Tags: actionscript-3, rest, post

I'm working with a Jetty based REST service wrote by a 3rd party developer to which I have to make calls from actionscript 3. There are multiple calls available and most of them work, there only one I'm having trouble with: To end a session I have to make a POST request to `http://localhost/control/end`.

I've made a basic test with [Simple Rest Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fhjcajmcbmldlhcimfajhfbgofnpcjmb) in Chrome and that works:

1. I get a status 200 response
2. In service's console I see a `setEnd` call made

The problem is, when I try the same in actionscript, it doesn't seem to work.
Here's my basic call:

```
private function deleteSID(event : MouseEvent) : void {
            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(SERVER+"control/end"); 
            request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
            var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, deletedSID);
            loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);
            loader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS , onHTTPStatus);
            loader.load(request);
        }
```

But I get a 404 instead of a 200, as if it's not actually doing a POST.

Unfortunately I don't have a lot experience with REST APIs, so any hint/tip on what I might be missing is appreciated.

Comment: The url you are posting to is cited as "http://localhost:control/end"  Because of the colon, I'm assuming `control` is supposed to be a port number. But then in creating the url request it's seems you are using control as a `String` and it is not a port number?

Comment: What's the content of SERVER const?

Anyway, try sending some data with your POST call:
var requestVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
requestVars.dummy = "lol";
request.data = requestVars;

Comment: sorry "localhost:control/end" is a mistake. @MarceloAssis I've done `request.data = 'oi';` that sorted it out. Would you like to post your solution as an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sending some data with your POST call:

```
var requestVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(); 
requestVars.dummy = "lol"; 
...
request.data = requestVars;
```